# Datepart(year, ...) vs. Year(...)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What are the advantages of using one over the other in the following:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

As opposed to:

```
YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Is there is a performance difference? If so, which one is the fastest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually - using `YEAR(..)` is preferably for me, since it's considered a **deterministic** function, so if I use this in a computed column definition

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD YearOfDate AS YEAR(SomeDateColumn)
```

I can make this column **persisted** (and store it into the table):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD YearOfDate AS YEAR(SomeDateColumn) PERSISTED
```

This does *not* work for `DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDateColumn)` (don't ask me why - just noticed this heuristically).

The same applies to `MONTH(SomeDate)` vs. `DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate)`.

If you have tables that you need to select from based on the month and year of a date (like `SalesDate` or something), then having month and years as **persisted computed** columns (and indexing them) can be a huge performance boost.

Comment: Interesting, I actually don't see this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab2f5/1/0). What am I missing?

Comment: Documentation in [SQL Server 2008 and 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.110).aspx) says that `datepart` is nondeterministic. For [SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.90).aspx) there is a list of the nondeterministic arguments to `datepart`. Looks like documentation has changed but SQL Server has not.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: interesting.... I could have **sworn** it didn't work with `DATEPART() AS PERSISTED` when I tried it...... but it does now. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @marc_s: interesting #2, I decided to try this for myself - SQL 2014...  Created a table with SSMS designer with one computed column defined with `YEAR` and the other defined with `DATEPART`.    Using SSMS, generating the create script yielded both columns defined with `DATEPART`

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates](
 [Day] [date] NOT NULL,
 [Year]  AS (datepart(year,[Day])) PERSISTED,
 [Year2]  AS (datepart(year,[Day])) PERSISTED,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Day] ASC)
)
`

Comment: interesting #3, I tried it again and had SSMS display the generated script, and it indeed included the `YEAR` computed column - which was converted back to `DatePart` when going back into the table designer.


`CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
 (
 Day date NOT NULL,
 Year1  AS YEAR([Day]) PERSISTED ,
 Year2  AS DATEPART(YEAR, [Day]) PERSISTED 
 )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

Answer (score 30):

There is no difference. In the execution plan both is translated to as `datepart(year,getdate())`.

This is true for SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012.

```sql
select datepart(year, getdate())
from (select 1 x) x

select year(getdate())
from (select 1 x) x
```

Execution plan.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.5057.00" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="1.157E-06" StatementText="select datepart(year, getdate())&#xD;&#xA;from (select 1 x) x&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;" StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" CachedPlanSize="8" CompileTime="23" CompileCPU="23" CompileMemory="64">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.157E-06">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1001" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <ConstantScan>
                <Values>
                  <Row>
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="datepart(year,getdate())">
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1002">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Intrinsic FunctionName="datepart">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Intrinsic FunctionName="getdate" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Intrinsic>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </ColumnReference>
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </Row>
                </Values>
              </ConstantScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="1.157E-06" StatementText="select year(getdate())&#xD;&#xA;from (select 1 x) x" StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" CachedPlanSize="8" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="64">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.157E-06">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1001" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <ConstantScan>
                <Values>
                  <Row>
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="datepart(year,getdate())">
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1002">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Intrinsic FunctionName="datepart">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Intrinsic FunctionName="getdate" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Intrinsic>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </ColumnReference>
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </Row>
                </Values>
              </ConstantScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```