# How to select only year from a Date Time TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm right now creating View and I need to display only the YEAR from a normal DateTime
How can I  do that to return just a Year as a value from ? 
I have already tried it with EXTRACT but somehow it not  working ..
Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: From Books Online: [Functions That Get Date and Time Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeParts)

Comment: Based on the two answers to this question, here's a question that compares `DATEPART()` and `YEAR()`, if anyone is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850239/datepartyear-vs-year

Comment: @valverij - The only difference is you can write `YEAR()` function faster than `DATEPART()` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`YEAR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function

```
SELECT YEAR(MyDateCol) FROM MyTable
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3756)

Comment: +1 - After years working with SQL, how did I not know this existed?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DATEPART()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract the year from datetime value.

```
DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE());
```

Check out ***[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13343)***

Answer (score 1):

Year function

```
SELECT YEAR(getdate())

SELECT YEAR(columnname) from yourtablename
```