# Efficiency: MONTH() vs. DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql-server, performance, datediff, datepart

I have two tables with dates, which I want to join with an INNER JOIN.
These tables are connected to each other with a FK that ensures me that a record on Tabla A and its' related record on Table B are in the same year.

Long story short - I want to make sure that the two dates are in the same month. as explained, DATEDIFF() has no logical advantage in my case - it will never give me -12 or 12 because the year is irrelevant to the equation. My results will always be the same with either DATEDIFF or MONTH (I tested it, of course).

With these assumptions - what would be more efficient?

```
    SELECT .... 
    FROM DatesA da 
    INNER JOIN DatesB db 
    ON MONTH(da.Date) = MONTH(db.Date) 
    AND [Rest of the join]

    SELECT .... 
    FROM DatesA da 
    INNER JOIN DatesB db 
    ON DATEDIFF(MM, da.Date, db.Date) = 0 
    AND [Rest of the join]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just in the same month? What about the same year, too? That first `SELECT` could give strange results when dealing with dates across more than one year.

Comment: The [Rest of the join] is dealing with another table, which represents years and other stuff. So I know I don't need to compare years, just months.

Comment: @user3367818 Then you should be comparing `MONTH() AND [some of the rest of the join, such as YEAR()]`'s combined performance to `DATEDIFF()`'s performance.

Comment: As for the actual question, you can only give the answer yourself by comparing the execution plans. I would only *expect* a single `datediff()` to be faster and more sargable, nothing more.

Comment: NB: `select datediff(MM, '2015-07-01', '2017-07-01') MonthsBetween` returns `24`; not `0`.  So this check will be checking that your dates are both the same month **and** the same year.

Comment: @JohnLBevan please read again... This is irrelevant in my case.

Comment: Cool; just checking explicitly; as this means you're really comparing `datediff(MM,da.date,db.date)=0` with `month(da.date) = month(db.date) and year(da.date) = year(db.date)`; i.e. not just with the performance of the `month` function alone.

Comment: Not exactly. I don't have a YEAR() in my query, I have a FK join to a "parent" record that represent a year (among other stuff). I can't skip this join and replace it with just the DATEDIFF().

Comment: Interesting question, so I ran a test on my data.  My initial thought was 1 datediff calculation would be faster than 2 month calls.  NOT SCIENTIFIC but the average of 6 runs, the month() was 20 ms faster and consistently lower than the datediff method

Comment: Ps. Though I can't answer your  question on `datediff` vs `month`; I can throw in another option; instead of `month` try `datepart(month,...)`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17956/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-monthdate-and-datepartmonth-date

Comment: @GSerg how is `datediff()` more sargable?

Comment: @Horaciux In my experience `datediff()` uses indices just fine. Looking at various posts around here on how it's not sargable, I would assume it may have something to do with the fact that usually I use it as `where datediff(d, date1, date2) = 0`, and that combination (`d`, `= 0`) is sargable. Or maybe it's just the `= 0` part.

Comment: I think the best performing method would be to add a persisted computed column with an index on each table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx

Comment: @GMastros would you consider to take a look at my proposed approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comparing Performance**

For me, testing with a data set of 2508 records with dates evenly spread through a single year, and joining the table to itself, `datepart` performed significantly better than `datediff` (the difference between `datepart` and `month` was negligable, though `datepart` was typically `~1ms` faster.  This test was done on `SQL 2008 R2 (SP3)`.  Full code shared below:

```
--prep
create table #testDates (d date)

insert #testDates
select dateadd(dd,row_number() over (partition by 1 order by number) % 365,'2017-01-01')
from master.dbo.spt_values a --, master.dbo.spt_values --uncomment this for a larger test set

select @@VERSION --Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6529.0 (X64) 
go


--test statements
set statistics time on
select count(1) --return 1 so we're measuring query time; not the time to return the results
from #testDates a 
inner join #testDates b 
on month(a.d) = month(b.d)
set statistics time off

set statistics time on
select count(1) 
from #testDates a 
inner join #testDates b 
on datepart(month,a.d) = datepart(month,b.d)
set statistics time off

set statistics time on
select count(1) 
from #testDates a 
inner join #testDates b 
on datediff(MM,a.d,b.d) = 0
set statistics time off

--cleanup
go
drop table #testDates
```

Timings were: `5ms`, `4ms`, `3432ms` respectively.

That said, this is only a test on my test data on my setup... it may vary considerably under different circumstances.

**How about indexed data?**

Adding an index after populating the data improved the performance of `datediff`; though only to `3390ms`; still leaving it far behind the others.

`create index ix_testDates_d on #testDates(d) --create the index after populating the data to ensure it's not fragmented`

**Other**

- Another reason to use `datepart`/`month` over `datediff` is this is better self-documenting code; i.e. it shows that you're looking for dates with the same month; rather than dates where the number of months between them is 0 (which is the same thing (years aside); but the latter takes a few moments more to cognitively process.
- A reason to use `datepart` over `month` is that `datepart` is ANSI compliant.
- However `month` has the advantage over `datepart` of being a deterministic function (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851564/361842), which for some reason `datepart` isn't!
- Also `month` is more intuitive; i.e. cognizantly quicker for people to comprehend.
- The choice between `datepart` and `month`, given the negligible performance difference, should be down to your other requirements and/or coding standards.

Comment: Hi, would you consider to take a look at my proposed approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - looks like the DateDiff approach could use indexes, since it's not a scalar function wrapping a value. A quick comparison in my environment on test data says DateDiff will be several times more efficient.

Comment: Funny, in my test I got the opposite ... to my surprise

Comment: very odd... I'm going to query a much larger set of data and see what I get.

Comment: I also tested it and it seemed like the MONTH was faster; I asked the question because it seemed illogical to me. I usually do DATEDIFF by default and I was afraid the results were influenced by the infrastructure (ran it on Production environment).

Comment: so the data I'm using has a nonclustered index on the date column, and includes the other columns I'm returning... I think the only way to know for sure is to look at estimated/actual execution plans in your environment and see what indexes may benefit each.

Comment: FYI: I've included some info on how I'm testing, as I found `datepart` to be fastest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42281644/361842.

Comment: Intuitively I'd suspect `datepart` to have been faster since it's plucking the month value then doing an integer comparison, rather than the calculations involved in converting the dates to months since 1900 then subtracting, then removing the sign (or equivalent steps; not sure what goes on under the surface; but the months between two dates are going to be more complex for SQL to calculate than the milliseconds between dates).

Answer (score 1):

I'll base my answer using previous answer by @JohnLBevan

This just scores 1ms. It is sergable soltion and make use of indexes in date column.

The "trick" is to previously have a kind of calendar table (that I create on the fly) having the first and last day of every month.

```
create table #testDates (d date)

insert #testDates
select dateadd(dd,row_number() over (partition by 1 order by number) % 365,'2017-01-01')
from master.dbo.spt_values a --, master.dbo.spt_values --uncomment this for a larger test set

select @@VERSION --Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6529.0 (X64) 
go


create index ix_testDates_d on #testDates(d) 

--test statements
set statistics time on
select count(1) --return 1 so we're measuring query time; not the time to return the results
from #testDates a 
inner join #testDates b 
on month(a.d) = month(b.d)
set statistics time off

select min(d) iniDay,max(d) endDay into #months from #testDates
group by month(d)


set statistics time on
select count(1) --return 1 so we're measuring query time; not the time to return the results
from #testDates a 
inner join #months m
on a.d>= m.iniDay and a.d<=m.endDay
inner join #testDates b 
 on b.d>= m.iniDay and b.d<=m.endDay
set statistics time off


--cleanup
go
drop table #testDates 
drop table #months
```

time was 4ms, 10ms for calendar table, 1ms .

For 150.000 rows

```
(150000 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 141 ms,  elapsed time = 130 ms.

(12 row(s) affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 14 ms, elapsed time = 14 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 48 ms.
```

Comment: Nice solution. You should include `#months` in your query's time though, if that needs to be run each time for the query to work. That said, if all dates are within a known range and you could prepopulate a permanent table with all months, you'd get the benefit without the overhead.